# Reference custom list form fields from code behind and automatically fill them with values

Tags: sharepoint, forms, code-behind

I`v made my custom NewForm.aspx for my list and I want to add some custom code to it. So I inherit that form from my own class:

```
public class MyCustomNewForm : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage
```

Now I want to reference some of available fields to automatically fill them for user. (Javascript won't help here as I have to get some data from other lists).

But I have no idea how do I reference these fields from codebehind files.

The code for control field is written (well, it was generated by Sharepoint Designer when using command *Insert > SharePoint Controls > Custom List Form...*) in .aspx page like this:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
```

When looking at id at runtime, it is insanely long

[alt text http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7495/ss20090713143352.png](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7495/ss20090713143352.png)

So how do i reference fields, so I could set *Text* property on them in my codebehind file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#Dont mind this painful solution, but scroll down to see edit.
Uhh, I`v found a workaround. But **warning!** if you don't need to use any Sharepoint objects to access any values dynamically, then this post is not for you, instead, you would like to read some of the referenced articles.

So, to pre-fill some fields in a NewForm.aspx with values from some other list, do the following.

**In short:**

1. Make your custom list item form. Do it [step-by-step](https://sharepointhelps.wordpress.com/2008/07/23/create-a-custom-list-form-for-a-sharepoint-list/).
2. Make a class that inherits from
   `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage`
3. Inherit that class on your custom form aspx <%@ Page. Mine looks like this: `Inherits="xx.MeetingWorkspace.Tasks_NewFormxx, xx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5"`
4. In `protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)` function use
   [FindControlRecursively](https://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/) to find
   a ContentPlaceHolder object with ID
   "PlaceHolderMain" (Call that
   function on this.Controls[0], not on
   this object).
5. Make `HtmlHiddenField` objects, assign values and add attribute "Title" using method `HtmlHiddenField.Attributes.Add()`. You will need that for step 7.
6. Add hidden fields to the
   ContentPlaceHolder you got
   previously.
7. Use Javascript (read [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209022337/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/sharepoint/archive/2007/06/21/using-javascript-to-manipulate-a-list-form-field.aspx) or [here](https://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2008/02/07/more-sharepoint-branding-customisation-using-javascript-part-1/)) to
   fill your desired fields from
   hidden field values to those fields
   that user sees.

P.S. I'm beginner at sharepoint so better use these steps with caution. I'd be glad to find out an answer where you can reference your fields in code, so I don't have to use any javascript stuff.

**My journey in long:**
As I mentioned, I inherited my own public class for this form. With this technique it should be possible to reference existing form field by declaring these class controls with a variable name as same as form ID. In screenshot I have a `TextBox` class object with ID *ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_77625.... etc.*

Now, in my class I tried making a variable with the same name as ID, but it does not initialize and the value is null. I thought maybe ID is being changed, I checked, but no, it stays as it was before.

So I tried using Control.FindControl, but it does not search recursively, so I found this article: [Recursive Page.FindControl](https://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/). (You would probably want to read some comments, as there are better implementations with generics). **Important:** Read comment "Sam on August 2, 2008 4:13 AM" before using FindControlRecursive method.

So, with the function in hand, I passed the ID as argument - still no luck, it just returns null for me. Luckily, I could pass PlaceHolderMain as ID and it would return me main placeholder object.

So the workaround would then be on the overriden method `OnInit(EventArgs)` make HtmlHiddenField objects, set their values to whatever you want and add those hidden fields to PlaceHolderMain . (`ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add()`)

Then with some javascript on ASPX page I was able to load values from hidden fields to my preffered fields (well I found a way to reference the fields I want with javascript. Two useful articles for this: [shorter one](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209022337/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/sharepoint/archive/2007/06/21/using-javascript-to-manipulate-a-list-form-field.aspx) and [longer one](https://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2008/02/07/more-sharepoint-branding-customisation-using-javascript-part-1/))

#Edit: Less painful solution
Ohh, glad i found this.
With [jPoint](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=jpoint) (jQuery for SharePoint) and then with some script you can use querystring parameters to prepopulate list fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//sharejpoint.googlecode.com/files/jPointLoader-0.6-expanded.js" ></script>
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    jP.Form.readForm();
    $.each(jP.Form.Items, function (idx, item) {
    if(querySt(item.Name) != null && querySt(item.Name) != "undefined")
      jP.Form[item.Name].val(unescape(querySt(item.Name)));
    });
   });

//Gets value of querystring key
function querySt(ji)
{
      hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
      gy = hu.split("&");
      for (i=0;i<gy.length;i++)
      {
              ft = gy[i].split("=");
              if (ft[0].toUpperCase() == ji.toUpperCase()) //Fixed query so it is case insensitive
              {
                      return ft[1];
              }
      }
}
</script>
```

This script can be found in comments in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/using-javascript-to-manipulate-a-list-form-field?PageIndex=10) article.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebDataForm` control in your code behind; call its method `FindControl(@ID)`.

You can figure out the ID from the page html generated; use IE developer tools it should be `$ff21_` for example which in this case `ID = ff21`